# How to make UI a solid color in CKeditor 4.5

Tags: ckeditor

How does one make the color of the UI toolbar of CKeditor solid rather than gradient? I've search the other questions and read that I need to edit a file skins.js, but there are no js files in the skins folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor **4.5** is not yet out there, so my assumption is that you use latest [major branch](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/major).

File you're looking for is [**skin.js**](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/skins/moono/skin.js) in particular skin directory (eg. mono).

The fact that you can't find this file in given directory might be caused by using builded (minified) CKEditor.

If you did [build CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build) then skin is likely to be minified to main file (but I'm not that familiar with building, so it's my guess).

If that's the case, you need to edit source version, and build it again.